# Exception handling not triggered/unexpected behaviour in program

Tags: java, exception, arguments

I have a java program that takes command line arguments and then converts the decimal value to its hexadecimal counterpart. I am trying to make use of an exception handling code block (try/catch) which is not being triggered. The try/catch block is intended to be triggered when no command line arguments are passed to the program.

Have ran program through Jenkins/SonarQube to identify code smells and remedy issues. Have utilised process of trial and error, to experiment with different possibilities to see if I can resolve the design flaw.

https://pastebin.com/frBq46zs

```
//import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dec2Hex
{
public static int Arg1;

public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter any number: ");
//Arg1= scan.nextInt();
//scan.close();
if (args.length < 0)
{
try
{
Arg1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
System.err.println("Argument" + args[0] + " must be an integer.");
System.exit(1);
}
}
```

Utilising if `(args.length > 0)` with no command line value results in the exception not being triggered. I thought that this was to be expected, because the exception block would never be triggered because the conditional statement has not been satisfied.

However, the converse was not as expected. I thought that if `(args.length==0)` then this would mean "no arguments have been passed, attempt to parse the value entered, at the command line. If still despite that, no value can be parsed, THEN trigger the catch statement generating the error message and output it to the user."

Whenever I use `args.length==0`  or `args.length<0` with no command line arguments submitted, all I get is a:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Message which specifically refers to the following line of code:

```
Arg1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

Comment: Check for `args.length == 0` and if it's true, then print an error message (and `return;` so the execution stops). You don't need to throw an exception for it. Also [see tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: Please verify your condition first, 
do you want check this -> if (args.length < 0) 
or if (args.length > 0)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `Arg1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` before method call `Integer.parseInt` method arguments will be resolved. So it will try to get first element from argument list (as Java array is 0 based it will get first element with index 0).

As you are not passing any command line argument, code is breaking during argument resolution. Because the array length is 0, `args[0]` is giving `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Which is an expected scenario. So you should case this exception as well.

```
try
{
Arg1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
System.err.println("No Argument Provided.");
System.exit(1);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
System.err.println("Argument" + args[0] + " must be an integer.");
System.exit(1);
}
```

And you don't need that if condition of checking for argument length, if you want to execute the exception code for 0 length. If you want to execute existing exception block pass argument that is not a number and remove the if condition.

In summary, code will reach to `NumberFormatException` block when you pass some argument and that is not a number. And that exception will be thrown by `Integer.parseInt`. And current exception is being thrown by `args[0]` because array length is 0 and you are trying to retrieve the first array element from empty array and it's throwing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**Although** it's not desirable to reach to exception code, while you can handle that even before that.